# Why can Victor suddenly control his transformation?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-four, fantastic-four-2

During the course of [*Fantastic Four*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120667/) *Victor von Doom* slowly mutates into some kind of metallic creature being able to shoot lightnings (and thus becomes *Dr. Doom*), a transformation that is completed at the end of the movie, when he seems to be completely made out of metal.

And yet in the sequel [*Fantastic Four: Rise of the Silver Surfer*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0486576/) he suddenly is back the old human *Victor* (while still being able to shoot lightnings) and his metal outfit is just a suit/mask. So **how come this change?** Is he now able to control his mutation, did I overlook something in the story (or maybe not in the movies but the comics, which I'm completely ignorant of), or is this just an inconsistency (and which version is then more true to the comics)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been a while since I've watched this movie, but I vaguely remember him having contact with the Silver Surfer, and that contact "healed" him.

Specifically, if I remember correctly, the radition the Silver Surfer uses is similer to what transformed the whole team, leading to Victor's cure and to the team having power swapping issues.

Comment: I don't remember him having contact with the Surfer before his first appearance. I think he just appeared out of nowhere in that Colonel's investigation staff. However it may be me not properly remembering it. If that really was the case, it could indeed be an explanation.

Comment: @ChristianRau he gets out of his `coffin` and seeks the silver surfer wearing a mask and hooded robe to conceal his disfigurement. After touching the silver surfer he turns more human. I wouldn't call it `healing` as much as `improved`. After contact with the surfer he is more powerful and no longer in pain.

Comment: Ah, Wikipedia says *"The Surfer's movements around the globe bring him past Latveria, where the cosmic energy affects Victor von Doom (Julian McMahon), freeing him from two years as a metal statue."*. Man I feel stupid posting such an uninformed question (shouldn't have built furniture while watching it ;)). Nearly urged to delete it, but well, at least you got some easy rep.

Comment: @ChristianRau oh I never picked that part up in the film. I didn't know it was the surfer who caused him to break free of his statue state.

Comment: "healed" look little vague here

Comment: @AnkitSharma i don't remember the specifics of how or why it fixed him, or even if it's explained in the movie.

Comment: @DForck42 as i remembered it kept vague in movie itself

Comment: @DForck42 I guess it was a similar effect as on *Johnny* who could switch powers with the others afterwards. In the end who could explain how their initial mutation was caused by that radiation cloud (or how a "mutation" could make you influence external forces, instead of dying from radiation or cancer), it's a comic.